# Sort and output from a logfile by date and time [DOS batch]

Tags: sorting, date, batch-file, time, dos

I want to sort the following example log by date and time

```
cccc.txt deleted. 02.02.1900 13:13:00,66
asdf.txt deleted. 30.09.2014 16:32:16,66
bbbb.txt deleted. 01.01.2000 00:05:00,00
```

The filenames wont always be 4 figgures so /+n wont work it seems.

Thx in advance!

Comment: How come one date is zero-padded and the other two aren't?

Comment: Are there any extra spaces in the first two terms?

Comment: No. I used !date! and !time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   set "var=%%a"
   for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=:., " %%b in ("!var:~-22!") do set "aaa%%d%%c%%b%%e%%f%%g=%%a"
)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%x in ('set aaa') do echo(%%y
pause
```